# Negative return value of the _snprintf() function

Tags: c

I am reviewing a legacy C code that calls `_snprintf()` function and then checks the status it returns to make amends if necessary.

As such, it checks for `status == count` being passed, which assumes that the count passed did not account for an extra NULL character, in which case the logic that I am reviewing is replacing the last character in the string with NULL.

Also, it checks for `status == -1`, and in that case creates an empty null-terminated string.

I was curious on which conditions the -1 value is returned, and found the following explanation in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/snprintf-snprintf-snprintf-l-snwprintf-snwprintf-l?view=msvc-170:

> If len > count, count characters are stored in buffer, no
> null-terminator is appended, and a **negative value** is returned.

You see, this article says just "negative value", without any distinction specifically for -1.  This makes me suspicious if it is possible it can return other negative values (-2, -3, etc.) which seems the documentation implies.  So I am curious as to what the specific negative return value means in this case, and most importantly, it looks to me that the existing code is not doing good enough work for testing for abnormal situation, and instead of checking for `status == -1`, it should be checking for `status < 0`.  So, is there a possibility to get back a negative number other than -1, and if so - what would it mean?

Comment: It returns a **negative** value, as stated. The doc says it returns `-1` specifically *If buffer is a null pointer and count is nonzero, or if format is a null pointer.* Other functions also return positive or negative values without specfying exactly `+1` or `-1` such as `strcmp()` and `isXXX()`.

Comment: Beware of changes to Microsft's implementation.  The modern `snprintf()` — without the leading underscore — follows the C standard.  The behaviour you cite is the old, non-standard behaviour.  The C standard says [`snprintf()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.5) returns _the number of characters that would have been written had `n` been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative value if an encoding error occurred. Thus, the null-terminated output has been completely written if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than `n`._

Comment: On the page you link to, it says (a long way further down): _Beginning with the UCRT in Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 10, `snprintf` is no longer identical to `_snprintf`. The `snprintf` function behavior is now C99 standard conformant._

Comment: It is an error return, the buffer was too small to also store the zero terminator.

Answer (score 2):

> *it looks to me that the existing code is not doing good enough work for testing for abnormal situation, and instead of checking for `status == -1`, it should be checking for `status < 0`*

Correct.

> *So, is there a possibility to get back a negative number other than -1*

Yes.

> *and if so - what would it mean?*

It means there was an error.

Documentation is often vague like that to make sure you *don't* check for a specific value. The exact value is likely an implementation detail and can change. Since it is not documented, you'd have to dig into the source code or run a bunch of tests to find out, but that would only be valid for that specific version of the function.

Note: do not try to use [`errno`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/errno-doserrno-sys-errlist-and-sys-nerr?view=msvc-170) unless it is specifically documented to set it. Lots of things inside the call to `_snprintf` can incidentally set `errno` giving you a false error flag.

There is [one documented instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/snprintf-snprintf-snprintf-l-snwprintf-snwprintf-l?view=msvc-170#return-value) where `errno` is set and there is a specific return value...

> If buffer is a null pointer and count is nonzero, or if format is a null pointer, the invalid parameter handler is invoked, as described in Parameter validation. If execution is allowed to continue, these functions return -1 and set errno to EINVAL.

Comment: What is the cite for the last "If buffer is a null pointer ..."?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It's from the docs in the question.

Comment: @Schwern, my concern was how likely is the possibility that another negative value other than -1 can cause the issue with this old code, and if I should invest the time in making the change (it is not a single place, it is all over the code).  The useful suggestion that you made is to see if I can "dig into the source code".  I probably should have done just that instead of asking the question and getting criticized for being alarmed.  Will learn my lesson and never ask questions here again. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @tulu Sometimes we don't get the answer we wanted. The point is *you cannot know how likely it is, only that it can happen*. Documentation is the standard to code by. The details of the implementation you might glean from the source code can change in the next release. This is common to all software libraries. Yes, you should make the change; it's more correct, will do no harm, simpler and faster and less error prone than digging around in the source code. Since it's scattered all over the code, consider taking the opportunity to wrap it in a function or macro.

Comment: @Schwern, I totally agree with you - and as you have advised - I dag down into the code, and eensure myself that the only negative value being returned by that std function is -1.  So - in order to be conscious of time  & costs, I am closing this issue.  There is no need for anyone to spend time making 1000 changes and retesting this great bulk of code. Your suggestion was simple to implement, so thank you for that.  There are many corrections that legacy code can benefit of - some may be necessary, some can be ignored. I consider this one to be the latter.  Thanks again.